# How to get the correct Wikipedia article

Tags: api, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm using the MediaWiki API to get the first paragraph of certain Wikipedia articles. Currently the issue I'm having is with terms that have multiple entries in Wikipedia. For example, the term Java brings up the Wikipedia article for the island Java, not the programming language. Is there some parameter that I should use to differentiate between the two?

Comment: Now, the term "Java" *does* refer to both topics. By what criterion do you want to differentiate? Do you know that you're searching for a programming language or what?

Comment: Essentially, I'd like to know if there's a parameter that will allow me to specify which term I'm referring to. Perhaps there's a category parameter that will let me do this, that I'm currently overlooking. That said, for this specific example, I'd like to retrieve Java the language.

Comment: Yes, there's an `incategory:` parameter; so if you know that category title you can use that.

Comment: MediaWiki is generic software for working with wikis on any topic in any structure, it knows nothing about the solutions the many editors of a particular wiki have evolved over the years to deal with issues such as disambiguation. The MediaWiki API doesn't know this either. The best you can do is learn the techniques used on the wiki your are interested in, such as which categories and templates are used. Then you can make some attempts to parse them, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check the categories. The article "Java" belongs to "Greater Sunda Islands" and the article "Java (programming language)" belongs to "C programming language family", "Class-based programming languages", "Concurrent programming languages", etc.

Answer (score -2):

check http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php for:

```
* list=querypage (qp) 

Parameters:
 qppage              - The name of the special page. Note, this is case sensitive
                    This parameter is required
                    One value: Ancientpages, BrokenRedirects, Deadendpages, Disambiguations, DoubleRedirects, Listredirects,
                        Lonelypages, Longpages, Mostcategories, Mostimages, Mostinterwikis, Mostlinkedcategories,
                        Mostlinkedtemplates, Mostlinked, Mostrevisions, Fewestrevisions, Shortpages,
                        Uncategorizedcategories, Uncategorizedpages, Uncategorizedimages, Uncategorizedtemplates,
                        Unusedcategories, Unusedimages, Wantedcategories, Wantedfiles, Wantedpages, Wantedtemplates,
                        Unwatchedpages, Unusedtemplates, Withoutinterwiki
```

I guess Mostrevisions , Mostlinked and Mostcategories can help you get a meaningful page.

here is an example on the usage: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=querypage&qppage=Ancientpages

Comment: I really don't think this is going to help here.

Comment: So you think when the one article has more revisions that another it's the one about a programming language?